# How would I use a string of image names to use in a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

I keep ending with an error saying that there are incompatible pointers assigning UIIMAGE to NSString.

```
self.imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"shop_deal.png",@"Date.png",@"Recreation.png",@"Productivity.png",nil];

        UIImageView *imgView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150)];
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imageNames];
        [self addSubview:imgView];
```

I'm doing something wrong here...

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imageNames];
```

you have to use an `NSString`, not an entire `NSArray`. So try:

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imageNames objectAtIndex:0]];
```

instead.